# c# des decrypt using Rfc2898DeriveBytes?

Tags: c#, des

I attempts to decrypt des in c #. Have a question. Need help.

1. The key should be 8 digits in length?

     -
2. Use the key to create Rfc2898DeriveBytes?

   - In Java KeySpec keySpec, SecretKey key is used. in c#?

Comment: Encryption protocols are language agnostic - it will be the same process/parameters in every language.

Comment: I see no relation between your question and the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class. Are you sure you know what you want to do and how? See [Why do I need to use the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class (in .NET) instead of directly using the password as a key or IV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly), [Encrypt/Decrypt String using DES in C# - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19538/Encrypt-Decrypt-String-using-DES-in-C),

Comment: because given 10-digit security key.