# C# Calculating Percentage of AES Encryption/Decryption

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, percentage

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt a file using AES 256 bit with the code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645527/aes-encryption-on-large-files). The full code I am using is seen [here](https://pastebin.com/tvaJaZi2). I was wondering how I could calculated the percentage done of both encryption/decryption in the while loop as it writes to the file. For example in encryption:

```
while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    //int percentage = Calculate percentage done here?
}
```

And in decryption:

```
while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    //int percentage = Calculate percentage done here?
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it worked with both encryption and decryption. For encryption, I used:

```
var percentComplete = (float)fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length;
```

As [John Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791540/john-wu) stated. For decryption, I used:

```
var percentComplete = (float)fsOut.Position * 100 / fsCrypt.Length;
```

This works because it divides the Position(x100) by the **total length of the encrypted file**, as opposed to fsOut.Length; which only returns the data that's been written out to the new decrypted file.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the percentage complete as follows:

```
var percentComplete = (float)fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length;
```

How you display it is up to you.  You can update a form control (you may need to use [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170448/how-to-invoke-a-ui-method-from-another-thread) if your cypto runs on a worker thread) or raise a [custom event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx) (e.g. `ProgressChanged`) and consume it in your UI thread.

Comment: Thank you, I've used this in my final answer where I also include how to show percentage for file decryption :)