# AES Decrypting c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I tried to decrypt bytes, but i have error "`length of data to decrypt is invalid`" in line `read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, len);` `inputFile.lenght = 4256, len = 4256`

This is the code of decrypting

```
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        fsCrypt.Seek(fsCrypt.Length - 376, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = 256;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
        List < byte > bytes = new List < byte > ();

        fsCrypt.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        read = 1;
        var len = Convert.ToInt32(fsCrypt.Length);

        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        fsCrypt.CopyTo(mem);
        mem.Position = 0;
        using(CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mem, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)) // CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read
         {
          //var buffer2 = new byte[len];
          while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
           foreach(var m in buffer)
           bytes.Add(m);
          }
         }
```

Can u help me? what is problem in this code ?

I took the example of the [AES encryption on large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645527/aes-encryption-on-large-files)

How i encrypt:

```
byte[] salt = GenerateRandomSalt();


 //convert password string to byte arrray
 byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

 //Set Rijndael symmetric encryption algorithm 71 246
 RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
 AES.KeySize = 256;
 AES.BlockSize = 128;
 AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


 var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
 AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
 AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

 AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
 var kk = key.ToString();


 FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);


 byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
 int read = 0;



 byte[] encrypted;
 using(MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
  using(CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
   fsIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

   while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    csEncrypt.Write(buffer, 0, read);
   }
   encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
  }
 }

 fsIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 fsIn.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

 fsIn.Seek(fsIn.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 fsIn.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
```

Comment: The length of your data you're decrypting is wrong

Comment: @JoePhillips i added code how i encode file, can u check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();` too early on your encryption, it must be after the the end of the using statement for `csEncrypt` so all data gets flushed out to the memory stream.

Also in your decryption you are starting way to early in the file

`fsCrypt.Seek(fsCrypt.Length - 376, SeekOrigin.Begin);` should likey be `fsCrypt.Seek(fsCrypt.Length - 32, SeekOrigin.Begin);` if your `salt.Length` was 32 when you wrote it out.

Lastly you also don't trim the salt off before you pass it to `mem` so you are passing the salt data in to the stream along with the cyphertext and it makes your message too long.

Comment: i moved line `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();` after  `using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))` [link](https://pastebin.com/y9ge5W5P) but when decrypt again i get error

Comment: thank you very much, and do not tell me how to cut salt from stream?

Comment: ty, i wrote this   `fsCrypt.SetLength(fsCrypt.Length-32);` and decode without errors and right, but i have so much space after text, in notepad++ show "NULL" [link](http://joxi.ru/12MQg4RiMxoEg2)

Comment: Oh, I think I understand

Comment: yeah, "NULL" i fix, but now added to the end "OЩ-ЖмЕЦФ»r’Іціъ"