# ITIs there a C# equivalent of `Memset` or `SecureZeroMemory`

Tags: c#, security, dll

I'm creating a Unity game, so I need some security for my save files and other sensitive data. To do so, I created some functions that use the built-in AES and RSA encryption methods. However, they are supposed to have some sort of 'memory clearing' function that automatically zeroes any memory that is no longer in use. The problem is, I can't find any equivalent for it in c#. The closest I could find is

```
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
public unsafe static extern bool ZeroMemory(byte* destination, int length);
```

but I have no clue how to use it (never used pointers before). Any help would be much appreciated.

***EDIT: Added code***

*Please note that I am calling these funnctions from my* `Main()` *program*

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Encryption_test;

class OurCodeWorld
{
    public static int _BlockSize = 128,
        _KeySize = 256,
        _Iterations = 50000;
    public static PaddingMode _PaddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    public static CipherMode _CipherMode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //  Call this function to remove the key from memory after use for security
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
    public unsafe static extern bool ZeroMemory(byte* destination, int length);
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a random salt that will be used to encrypt your file. This method is required on FileEncrypt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] GenerateRandomSalt(int size = 32)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[size];

        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size/6; i++)
            {
                // Fill the buffer with the generated data
                rng.GetBytes(data);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts a file from its path and a plain password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputFile">The file to encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="password">The key used to encrypt the file</param>
    public static void FileEncrypt(string inputFile, string password)
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645527/aes-encryption-on-large-files

        //generate random salt
        byte[] salt = GenerateRandomSalt();

        //create output file name
        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile + Program.encryptedExtension, FileMode.Create);

        //convert password string to byte arrray
        byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        //Set Rijndael symmetric encryption algorithm
        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged
        {
            KeySize = _KeySize,
            BlockSize = _BlockSize,
            Padding = _PaddingMode
        };

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly
        //"What it does is repeatedly hash the user password along with the salt." High iteration counts.
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, _Iterations);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

        //Cipher modes: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52665/which-is-the-best-cipher-mode-and-padding-mode-for-aes-encryption
        AES.Mode = _CipherMode;

        // write salt to the begining of the output file, so in this case can be random every time
        fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        //create a buffer (1mb) so only this amount will allocate in the memory and not the whole file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
        int read;

        try
        {
            while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                //Application.DoEvents(); // -> for responsive GUI, using Task will be better!
                cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            // Close up
            fsIn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts an encrypted file with the FileEncrypt method through its path and the plain password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputFile"></param>
    /// <param name="outputFile"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public static void FileDecrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password, int saltLength = 32)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged
        {
            KeySize = _KeySize,
            BlockSize = _BlockSize
        };
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, _Iterations);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Padding = _PaddingMode;
        AES.Mode = _CipherMode;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];

        try
        {
            while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                //Application.DoEvents();
                fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex_CryptographicException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CryptographicException error: " + ex_CryptographicException.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            cs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error by closing CryptoStream: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fsOut.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using `string` you cant *out-of-the-box* (as they are immutable), if you are using *arrays* you can set them to *zero* with a `for` loop, or you could use *pointers* or `fixed` and `unsafe`, or other *unmanaged-memory*. The problem is we cant see your code to advise you

Comment: @TheGeneral If it's an array I would use [Array.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=netframework-4.8) which may even use memset internally.

Comment: @ckuri sure you can

Comment: @TheGeneral @ckuri It is supposed to go at the start of the `Main()` Function, but I have now split that into several other functions. If I want to use it in a function, how do I use it. Also adding code

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here, feel free to add to it.
`ZeroMemory` is not a C# method, it's an unmanaged (probably C/C++) one that's stored in a windows dll `Kernel32.dll`, called `RtlZeroMemory` in the land of low-level code. That's what the `extern` modifier and `DllImport` attribute do; they tell .Net that I want to grab a method from the `.dll` and use it.

Technically, there is a solution - just use pointers like so (but I'm not sure how similar to the original this is):

```cs
public static unsafe void ZeroMemory(byte* ptr, int length)
{
    //Loop to cover all the bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        //Set the byte at the index of (start + i) to 0
        *(ptr + i) = 0;
}
```

My question originally stemmed from a lack of understanding of what I was doing, so I got confused about everything (like how to use the method), which is why I posted my question. I was attempting to zero the key so that it couldn't be read from memory, which should be doable by using the above code.