# How to extract a single decrypted page from multi page file using AES256 algorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, filestream, encryption-symmetric

I have created a Winform test application for checking **AES256** encryption/decryption working for large files.

I have a Single Text file which is containing multiple pages in it, it's size is 7.32GB and total pages was 1.8 millions.

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt this multi pages text file using AES256 algorithm.

Currently it is taking 3 mins in encrypting and almost 3 mins in decrypting.
But i have below concern,

"*so if we wanted to extract a single page from that document, would we need to completely decrypt it? or is there any way so that we could access pieces of the file from without incurring the overhead?*"

I have used below code:

Encryption:

```csharp
public static void Encrypt(string password, string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645527/aes-encryption-on-large-files

    //generate random salt
    byte[] salt = GenerateRandomSalt();

    //create output file name
    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile + ".aes", FileMode.Create);

    //convert password string to byte arrray
    byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    //Set AES symmetric encryption algorithm
    AesManaged AES = new AesManaged();
    AES.KeySize = 256;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly
    //"What it does is repeatedly hash the user password along with the salt." High iteration counts.
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

    //Cipher modes: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52665/which-is-the-best-cipher-mode-and-padding-mode-for-aes-encryption
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    // write salt to the begining of the output file, so in this case can be random every time
    fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

    //create a buffer (1mb) so only this amount will allocate in the memory and not the whole file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
    int read;

    try
    {
        while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            //Application.DoEvents(); // -> for responsive GUI, using Task will be better!
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        // Close up
        fsIn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
    //using (FileStream infs = File.OpenRead(inputfile))
    //using (FileStream outfs = File.Create(outputfile))
    //    Encrypt(password, infs, outfs);
}
```

Decryption:

```csharp
public static void Decrypt(string password, string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];

    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
    fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    AesManaged AES = new AesManaged();
    AES.KeySize = 256;
    AES.BlockSize = 128;
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

    int read;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];

    try
    {
        while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            //Application.DoEvents();
            fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex_CryptographicException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CryptographicException error: " + ex_CryptographicException.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        cs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error by closing CryptoStream: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        fsOut.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
}
```

Please suggest a way to achieve it, if possible.

Comment: I don't follow why you'd link http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52665/which-is-the-best-cipher-mode-and-padding-mode-for-aes-encryptio, which says "ECB sucks", and then use ECB...

Comment: As it happens, ECB lets you do this (each block is encrypted independently, so you can just decrypt specific blocks), but the fact that it sucks horribly is still true. Normally you've use CTR for this, but you have to be very VERY careful to never reuse the same counter/IV combination

Comment: @canton7 ,
Thank you for reply,
Will CTR do this without incurring the overhead for this large piece of pages?

If possible, can you please give an example code ?

Comment: Yes, you can use CTR to decrypt any given block, without decrypting the blocks before it. Implementing crypto is hard: you need to understand it properly before you even stand a chance at doing in a vaguely safe way. If you're just copying examples, you don't understand it well enough

Comment: @canton7 ,

I am giving my best t undersand it, meanwhile,
Can you please suggest a good web link to know more related to my concern?

Comment: Cryptography Engineering Design Principles and Practice by Ferguson, Schneier and Kohno is a good primer