# ASP.NET MVC 4 Hash algorithm

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, hashcode, password-encryption

Which Hash algorithm is being used by default in ASP.NET MVC 4 when using asp.net identity. How does it work? How secure is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher, how does it work and is it secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity uses [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). It is implemented using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

[This answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly) goes into some details of the how and why. This is a very broad question and the answer can span many many pages. Perhaps you can google about the specifics yourself. I tried googling and there is a ton you can read about depending on your level of curiosity.