# Aes encryption in .net Core 3.0 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.0

Using .Net Core 3.0 I want to encrypt some text, using any password length as an encryption key:

```
using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
{
   var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey");
   myAes.Key = key; //ERROR
}
```

I get an error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Read the docs - AES has a required minimum key length.

Comment: Yes, but how do I translate any size of key to something AES can accept as a key? There is not much more in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: A password is not an AES key. Use some hash algorithm on the password that gives you a constant size you can use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You did wrong here- `var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey");`
[Refer Documentation here Aes Class](https://aesencryption.net)
     and [AES Documentation](https://aesencryption.net)

I suggest you by using `LegalKeySizes property` in AES class you can check the valid size of your key. The valid key sizes are specified by the particular symmetric algorithm implementation and are listed in the LegalKeySizes property.

```
 public virtual KeySizes[] LegalKeySizes { get; }
```

You will get the below output

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey");
  //myAes.Key = Key; //ERROR
   KeySizes[] ks = myAes.LegalKeySizes;
   foreach (KeySizes item in ks)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Legal min key size = " + item.MinSize);
    Console.WriteLine("Legal max key size = " + item.MaxSize);
    //Output
    // Legal min key size = 128
    // Legal max key size = 256
   }
```

if you are using `128 bit then Length of secret key should be 16 for 128 bits key size`
   Try this one

```
 var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey123456");
```

> For 192 bit - Length of the secret key should be 24 for 192 bits key
>   size  sample key will be like this

```
mysmallkey12345512987651
```

> For 256 bit - Length of the secret key should be 32 for 256 bits key
>   size      sample key

```
mysmallkey1234551298765134567890
```

Comment: I am glad to help you..!

Comment: How is it calculated? If key size is 128 bits, then how are we concluding the length of key to 16 characters? 8 bits = 1 byte. So, 16 * 8 = 128?

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of this encryption string extension. Not only does it address the key issue, but it also enables you to use a key of any length.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt a base64-encoded cipher text using AES encryption with a provided key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clearText">The string to be encrypted.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The encryption key.</param>
    /// <returns>The encrypted string.</returns>
    public static string Encrypt(this string clearText, string key)
    {
        // Constants for encryption
        const int KeySize = 128;
        const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

        // Generate random bytes for salt and initialization vector (IV)
        var saltStringBytes = New128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var ivStringBytes = New128BitsOfRandomEntropy();

        // Derive a key from the password and salt using PBKDF2
        using var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);

        // Create an AES encryption algorithm
        using var symmetricKey = Aes.Create();

        // Create an encryptor
        var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes);

        // Create memory streams for encryption
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            streamWriter.Write(clearText);
        }

        // Combine salt, IV, and encrypted data into the final cipher text
        var cipherTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
        cipherTextBytes = [.. cipherTextBytes, .. ivStringBytes, .. memoryStream.ToArray()];

        // Convert the combined data (salt, IV, and encrypted data) to a Base64-encoded string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a base64-encoded cipher text using AES encryption with a provided key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">The encrypted text to be decrypted.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The secret key used for decryption.</param>
    /// <returns>The decrypted plain text.</returns>
    public static string Decrypt(this string cipherText, string key)
    {
        // Constants for decryption
        const int KeySize = 128;
        const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

        // Convert the base64-encoded cipher text to bytes
        var cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // Extract the salt and IV (Initialization Vector) from the cipher text
        var saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(KeySize / 8).ToArray();
        var ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(KeySize / 8).Take(KeySize / 8).ToArray();

        // Derive the encryption key from the provided key and salt
        using var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);

        // Create an AES cipher with the derived key
        using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();

        // Create a decryptor with the key and IV
        var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes);

        // Decrypt the cipher text
        var originalCipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText).Skip(KeySize / 8 * 2).ToArray();

        // Create a memory stream to hold the original cipher text
        using var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(originalCipherText);

        // Create a crypto stream to perform decryption
        using var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        // Create a stream reader to read the decrypted data
        using var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

        // Return the decrypted plain text
        return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
    }

    // Generates 128 bits of random entropy (16 bytes) using a pseudo-random number generator.
    private static byte[] New128BitsOfRandomEntropy()
    {
        // Create an array of 16 bytes, which equals 128 bits.
        var randomBytes = new byte[16];

        // Initialize a random number generator.
        var random = new Random();

        // Generate random bytes and fill the array.
        random.NextBytes(randomBytes);

        // Return the generated random entropy (128 bits).
        return randomBytes;
    }
```